# How to have SQL and database createdAt dates match exactly?

Tags: swift, database, message

I have an app which includes a functionality which allows users to send messages to one another. The process for sending the message involves saving the sent message to the sender's internal SQL database while at the same time saving the message to the overall app's database, which is a parse-server (and then actually send the message via push notifications to the recipient). What I am concerned about is with the discrepancy that is bound to arise between the 'createdAt' parameter for the message in the database and the same parameter for that message in the SQL database. The reason for the perceived discrepancy is because I have it set up as follows:

```
import Parse
func sendMessage(){
    let newMessage = newMessage(messageString: "Hi", createdAt: Date()) 
    //drop the newMessage into the SQL table... will save the Date() as a String at time A
    let newMessageToDB = PFObject(className: "messages")
    newMessageToDB["messageString"] = newMessage.messageString
    //parse-server will automatically give the object a "createdAt" parameter when saved
    newMessageToDB.saveInBackground()
    //Since this is created automatically, the value will be the exact moment
    //the object is saved to the DB, at time B
}
```

Since the `createdAt` value for SQL is created by `Date()`, this value is set at time A. The `createdAt` for the database is created by the completion of the async function `saveInBackground()` and will therefore be saved at time B. With this method, I can in no way guarantee that time A = time B. This creates the problem that for the recipient the time of the message will be time B from the database (which will be put into *their* SQL table with time B), while, for the sender, the time of the message will be time A.
**My question**:
1. First and foremost, does this discrepancy even matter? The entire explanation of the problem might be irrelevant if this difference doesn't actually create any issues.
2. If it *is* relevant and *may* cause issues, how do I fix it? I know I can send it to the server, and then read the value back immediately after it is created to get the database's 'createdAt' to be saved in the SQL statement, but is that inefficient? To save an object, then immediately read it back from the DB to extract a value?

Comment: it looks to me you should take the createdAt info from sending client, and use that in both saves, both sending client, and server. In fact, you might want to save both values, like putting server's create time as "received at". And even you might want a "dispatchedAt". Differences between these values will tell you where your bottleneck (or lag) is.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu, I understand what you are saying, but how can I save the client's 'createdAt' and save it to the server's 'createdAt' if the server creates that on its own (I cannot manually assign a value to the server's 'createdAt'). I guess I could create a new parameter in the server for the objects like 'clientCreatedAt' and use that instead and just never touch the automatically constructed 'createdAt'?

Comment: yes, you send the clientCreated at info alongside your message, inside same object, save it in a different column on your server. dont need to touch servers createdAt.